# Highest possible place of non-zero Koszul homology

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Commutative Noetherian local ring. Let $K^R$ be the Koszul complex on a minimal generating set of $\mathfrak m$. Then, is it true that $H_i(K^R)=0$ for all $i>\mu(\mathfrak m)-\text{depth } R $ ?

This is clearly true if $\text{depth } R=0$ as the last non-zero module in the Koszul complex is the $\mu(\mathfrak m)$-th place. But I'm not sure what happens if $R$ has positive depth.

Please help.

Comment: Why the downvote :( ? I am new here, please kindly let me know if my question is not properly phrased by this site's standards